# Boostrap Table: get the row data by row index

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

In [Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)
, one field has anchor tag, so when clicked i can get the data-index of parent row. Now i want to get the complete row data using the **data-index**

```
  $(document).on('click', '.delete_icon', function(event) {
    var index = $(this).parent().parent().data('index');
    //Get the complete row data by using the dataindex
    // Row has three fields

  });
```

I cannot use **data-uniqueid** to get the data since my unique id is String like #1:1, #1:2 etc

Comment: could you provide HTML markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can obtain the row, index and data of the table with a click.

```
window.actionEvents = {
   'click .dele_icon': function (e, value, row, index) {
      alert('You click remove icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
      console.log(value, row, index);
   }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/39/